# service fabric java application deployment failed in local cluster

Tags: java, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless, guest-executable

I am new to service fabric and trying to deploy java application to local service fabric cluster with 5 nodes. i am using Ubuntu VM and following below steps to build and deploy it in asf cluster. while deploying i am getting below error. i tried to deploy in asf remote cluster also and got the same issue. Can you please help me on this.

Link :[Jav Application deploymen to ASF cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-quickstart-java-spring-boot)

Error code: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after spending some time in ASF logger. The issue was my YO generator was not working properly. i mean Yo json file was correpted. i run yo doctor and corrected it. its work

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this out and it worked for me so just going to ask some questions to make sure we didn't miss anything from the documents.

Under DhrumilSpringServiceFabric->DhrumilSpringGettingStartedPkg -> code, do you have two files?

1. gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar
2. entryPoint.sh

The entryPoint.sh file should have the following contents:

`#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
cd $BASEDIR
java -jar gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar`

Additionally, in the ServiceManifest.xml (located in DhrumilSpringServiceFabric->DhrumilSpringGettingStartedPkg), there should be the following snippet:

```
   <CodePackage Name="code" Version="1.0.0">
  <EntryPoint>
     <ExeHost>
        <Program>entryPoint.sh</Program>
        <Arguments></Arguments>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
     </ExeHost>
  </EntryPoint>
```

The **Program** property value "entryPoint.sh" has to be identical including casing with what's in your "code" folder.

If the above all check out, then please respond and happy to dive deeper into this.

Answer (score 0):

@Dhrumil Shah, I replicated the steps provided in the document and was able to achieve the desired results successfully.

Can you let me know if your java application is working fine without using service fabric and if you are using cli for your deployment?

Also, please check if java is installed properly on your VM. Check the below link for more information:

[Java Webapp Deployment in Azure Service fabric explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622029/java-webapp-deployment-in-azure-service-fabric-explorer)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aman.. I found the issue after spending some time in ASF logger. The issue was my YO generator was not working properly. i mean Yo json file was correputed. i run yo doctor and corrected it. its works.